# How to properly detect if a DOM element has a scrollbar in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

here's the problem: I have an horizontal list of elements that an API populates (this one in called in the created() hook). When the list is populated, depending on the items number, it could have a horizontal scrollbar and I want to detect this situation.

I know that in Vue you have to control the DOM based on your data, but i tried to think a way to get this relying on that, but i couldn't: i cannot "predict" if my element "will" have the scrollbar based on how many items it contain (something like "if this.items > 50 => 'it has a scrollbar'), because it's responsive, and so I thought there was an css or js property that could told me that.

At first, I thought: "simple, let's create a watcher for the data property that I fill with the API call, and then call this script (on data this.mainPanelHasScrollbar is initialized on false):

```
let element = document.querySelector('.truck-section')

if (element) {
    this.mainPanelHasScrollbar = element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth
}
```

My problem is that "document.querySelector" is null on:
**create**()
**create**() after the API CALL
**mounted**()
**API data filled property watcher**()

But it' correctly valued on
**API data filled property watcher**() with a barbaric setTimeout(//do calculation, 1000)
**updated**() //but it's too late for me

So, what I'm doing wrong? There is a best practices in cases like this?

Thanks you all
sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have to wait for the DOM to be renderered in order to get your element, so the `created` hook is not suitable for this. Your best shot would be after your promise is resolved + `this.$nextTick()` to make sure the dom is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I structured my code based on this and it worked.